# How to style google cse

Tags: html, css, google-custom-search

I've got this code from google but I'm unable to style it, I put new rule in my site's css but it doesn't listen to it and overrides it with google's default, what can I do with it to make it look as I want it to instead of how google planned it?

That's my css that gets ignored

```css
.cse .gsc-control-cse, .gsc-control-cse {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  width: 280px;
}
```

and that's the google cse code

```js
<script>
  (function() {
    var cx = '013795634587489910289:wcfxuut_dc8';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

Comment: have you tried adding "!important" to your properties??

Comment: I have tried but it didn't help at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the stylesheet in which your

```
.cse .gsc-control-cse, .gsc-control-cse {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  width: 280px;
}
```

styles are *after* google's css.

e.g. your html might look something like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cloud.google.com/compute/style.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/page.css" type="text/css">
```

Where `https://cloud.google.com/compute/` holds the style for the google gcs, and `style/page.css` holds the `.cse .gsc-control-cse, .gsc-control-cse { ... }`
styles.

### As a last ditch attempt, use only If you have to:

**(thanks to @MrUpsidown for pointing out that this method is [inherently bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css/3706876#3706876))**
<s>Add `!important` after each CSS rule:</s>

```
.cse .gsc-control-cse, .gsc-control-cse {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border: none !important;
  width: 280px !important;
}
```

---

The `!important` css declaration is used to override another style applied to the same element.
More info here: http://www.webcredible.com/blog-reports/web-dev/css-important.shtml

Comment: Ok thanks! I was doing it wrong I put border:none; !important instead of border: none !important;

Comment: Good question as I couldn't find any information about that in the google documentation. Bad answer as we definitely do **not** want to do that.

Comment: Because there should be another way to do that. Using `!important` is not a good idea. You can find a lot of information about that fact on the web. Here is a good summary: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3706876/1238965

Comment: Point taken, have updated my answer. Thank you @MrUpsidown

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed, that this question is 6 years and 9 months old, and there is a new version of the gsce. My solution is very simple:

CSS:

```css
    .gsce-search-outter {
      max-width: 35ch; /* about 35 characters long, give or take a few from google's own styling */
    }
```

HTML:

```html
    <script async src="{URL}"></script>
    <div class="gsce-search-outter"><div class="gcse-search"></div></div>
```

Demo Snippet:

```css
.gsce-search-outter {
  max-width: 35ch;
}
```

```html
<!--Note: the src is a demo by google-->
<script async src="https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=977e2d39cba1e462e">
</script>
<div class="gsce-search-outter">
<div class="gcse-search"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note: the width does include the search button, so add about 4-6ch

Comment: So just ... inline css?  Doesn't address the problem the other Q's do which is when you want to override the default CSS that google sets